# TRegEx, creating patterns for reading expressions from text

Tags: c++builder

I need help extending the pattern with another condition.
The following pattern:

`> \b\d{6}-\d(?:[0-9]|[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z]))?(?:[A-Za-z]{1,2})?\b`

applies to expressions:

```
> 111123-1,
> 111123-1X,
> 111123-1XZ,
> 111123-21,
> 111123-21Z,
> 111123-21ZX,
```

What should a pattern look like that would also include optional word 'INV' or 'PL' after char space?

```
> 111123-1 INV,
> 111123-1X INV,
> 111123-21 INV,
> 111123-21Z INV,
```

I tried this but it not works:

> \b\d{6}-\d(?:[INV][PL][A-Za-z0-9])?\b

Answer (score 2):

The 1st pattern you have shown does not match *any* the expressions you have provided. This is because you have `\b` and `1` inverted at the beginning of the pattern. You need to swap them, and then set `d{6}` to `d{5}` to account for the leading `1`, eg:

`\b1\d{5}-\d\d?[A-Za-z]?\b`

However, this fix will only match 4 of the 6 expressions you have provided.  This is because `\d?` allows only 0 or 1 digit, and `[A-Za-z]?` only allows 0 or 1 letter, so `111123-1XZ` and `111123-213` don't match.

Any of these patterns will match all 6 expressions:

`\b1\d{5}-\d\d*[A-Za-z]*\b`
`\b1\d{5}-\d\d?[A-Za-z0-9]*\b`
`\b1\d{5}-\d[A-Za-z0-9]*\b`

That being said, to support `INV` or `PL`, simply add `( (INV|PL))?` before the last `\b`, eg:

`\b1\d{5}-\d([A-Za-z0-9])*( (INV|PL))?\b`

Comment: My mistake in first pattern. Should be: \b\d{6}-\d\d?[A-Za-z]?\b

Comment: @Jacek please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers. Now most of my answer no longer applies after I spent a lot of time working on it. You can *add* new information, but don't *change* information that was already referred to. It just confuses future readers. In any case, the last sentence in my answer still applies to your new pattern.